# The method getDriverWrapper() is undefined for the type ITestExecutionContext

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, testing, automation

I created a custom Api for dynamic wait in provar and facing issue in geting refrence of current WebDriver instance. please help me out.

"WebDriver driver = testExecutionContext.getDriverWrapper().getDriver();" this line gives me an compilation error.

```
package customapis;

import java.util.logging.Logger;
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedConditions;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.WebDriverWait;
import com.provar.core.model.base.api.ValueScope;
import com.provar.core.testapi.ITestExecutionContext;
import com.provar.core.testapi.annotations.*;

@TestApi(title="Implicit Wait", summary="", remarks="", iconBase="", defaultApiGroups={"Custom"})
@TestApiParameterGroups(parameterGroups={
    @TestApiParameterGroup(groupName="inputs", title="Inputs"),
    @TestApiParameterGroup(groupName="result", title="Result"),
})
public class ImplicitWait {

    @TestApiParameter(seq=1, summary="The locator type.", remarks="", mandatory=true, parameterGroup="inputs")
    public String LocatorType;
    
    @TestApiParameter(seq=2, summary="The locator value.", remarks="", mandatory=true, parameterGroup="inputs")
    public String LocatorValue;

    @TestApiParameter(seq=3, summary="The timeout value.", remarks="", mandatory=true, parameterGroup="inputs")
    public int Timeout;

    @TestApiParameter(seq=10, summary="The name that the result will be stored under.", remarks="", mandatory=true, parameterGroup="result")
    public String Element;

    @TestApiParameter(seq=11, summary="The lifespan of the result.", remarks="", mandatory=true, parameterGroup="result", defaultValue="Test")
    public ValueScope resultScope;

    @TestLogger
    public Logger testLogger;
    
    @TestExecutionContext
    public ITestExecutionContext testExecutionContext;

    
    
    @TestApiExecutor
    public void execute() {

        WebDriver driver = testExecutionContext.getDriverWrapper().getDriver();
        WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, Timeout);
        By locator;

        switch (LocatorType) {
            case "id":
                locator = By.id(LocatorValue);
                break;
            case "name":
                locator = By.name(LocatorValue);
                break;
            case "className":
                locator = By.className(LocatorValue);
                break;
            case "tagName":
                locator = By.tagName(LocatorValue);
                break;
            case "linkText":
                locator = By.linkText(LocatorValue);
                break;
            case "partialLinkText":
                locator = By.partialLinkText(LocatorValue);
                break;
            case "cssSelector":
                locator = By.cssSelector(LocatorValue);
                break;
            case "xpath":
                locator = By.xpath(LocatorValue);
                break;
            default:
                throw new IllegalArgumentException("Invalid locator type: " + LocatorType);
        }

        WebElement element = null;
        try {
            element = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(locator));
        } catch (Exception e) {
            testLogger.info("Element not found within the specified wait time: " + e.getMessage());
        }

        // Store the result (if appropriate).
        testExecutionContext.setValue(Element, element, resultScope);
    }
}
```

[how can i fix it.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TrU05.png)

**Questions:**

How can I correctly retrieve the WebDriver instance within a custom API in Provar?
What might be causing the compilation error?
Could you provide a working example of a custom API that implements dynamic wait in Provar?

**Desired outcome:**

A functional custom API for dynamic wait in Provar
Understanding of the correct way to access the WebDriver instance within custom APIs

I appreciate any assistance or guidance you can provide.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.